# w3c validation of <a> inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript to set makers for google maps. Inside the markers I have links `<a>link</a>` to display on the map.

Howver the W3C valdiator complains about the `>` at the end of the opening `<a>`. I have tried replacing it with `&gt;` but it complained about the `&`.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

```
["<a href='/thebrianboru'>The Brian Boru</a>&lt;br />5 Prospect R…
```

Comment: Did you close the `<a>`-Tag? And wh do you write `&lt;br/>` instead of `<br/>`?

Comment: yes I have the link tag closed and I had to use &lt; instead of < for the br tag as I got errors and that was the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're using XHTML.  Wrap your code in a commented out [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

// Now I won't complain :)
var x = '<7>%></a>#$#><>><&&>';

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like XHTML? Put the JavaScript in a CDATA section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA to tell the interpreter, that it should ignore special characters like < > and &.

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
    // ...
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is inside of a `<script></script>` block in HTML, it could cause problems:

> The script should not contain the sequence
>
> `</` because it could be confused with the `</script>`. Inserting a
>   backslash between < and / in strings avoids the problem.
>
> `<\/`

http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of them below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
YOUR JS CODE .........
alert("www.mykitchenroom.com");
// -->
</script>
```

OR,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
YOUR JS CODE .........
alert("www.scienceanddevelops.com");
//]]>
</script>
```

W3C will don't check your code.

Thanks And Regards,
Subhojit Mukherjee